# In expressjs, Dustjs Multiple templates not working

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

In expressjs, Dustjs Multiple templates not working getting **500 Error: Template Not Found: template**

my base dust template as below **(template.dust)**

```
<div class="page">
  {+pageHeader}Hello World!{/pageHeader}
  <div class="bodyContent">
    {+bodyContent/}
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    {+pageFooter}
       <hr>
       <a href="/contactUs">Contact Us</a>
    {/pageFooter}
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to call this base template inside my home.dust I am getting error as below

```
Express
500 Error: Template Not Found: template
at Object.load (C:\office\nodejs-example\express_example\node_modules\application-name\node_modules\dust\lib\dust.js:54:27)
at Chunk.partial (C:\office\nodejs-example\express_example\node_modules\application-name\node_modules\dust\lib\dust.js:407:15)
at body_0 (undefined:1:130)
at Array.0 (C:\office\nodejs-example\express_example\node_modules\application-name\node_modules\dust\lib\dust.js:34:7)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

**"home.dust"**

```
{>"template"/}
{<pageHeader}
   {?username}
     Welcome {username} <a href="/items">Items</a> | <a href='/logout'> Log Out</a>
      {:else}
         <form method="POST" action="/signin">
            <label>Usename <input type="text" name="username" id="s-user"></label>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login">
         </form>
      {/username}
{/pageHeader}
```

routes class method

```
exports.home = function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {username :  req.session.username});

};
```

Comment: I put up an example here...also driving me crazy. index.dust is supposed to override the content block in base.dust: https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo/tree/master/demo/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dustjs-linkedin package with consolidate package (dustjs package is no longer maintained). Both are on npm. You can use dust templates with a layout by doing the following:

layout.dust

```
  <body>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
{+content}
This is the base content.
{/content}
  </body>
```

index.dust (homepage partial)

```
{>"views/layout.dust"/}
{<content}
This is loaded from a partial.
{/content}
```

app.js

```
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin')
, cons = require('consolidate');

app.engine('dust', cons.dust);
```

Full Example: https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem I wrote: [klei-dust](https://npmjs.org/package/klei-dust) which is a helper, like consolidate, to use dustjs-linkedin together with express 3.x. 
The primary difference between klei-dust and consolidate.dust is that the former don't need partials and base template paths relative to app root, and doesn't require you specifying template file extension as well.

Your `index.dust` could then look like:

```
{>layout/}
{<content}
    Body content...
{/content}
```

Given you have a `layout.dust` in the same folder as `index.dust`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone with this problem and this issue has driven me crazy! The author of Express has explained, that there is an issue in consolidate (package which uses Dust in Express).

> yeah there's an issue open in consolidate for this sort of thing,
>   these engines that do not provide
>   this mechanism are pretty clumsy right now

By: The author of Express(tjholowaychuk) [from google groupes](http://bit.ly/O3xGdb)

Comment: I have tried this [package](https://npmjs.org/package/klei-dust) and it works great with Express 3.x. Now you are able to use Dust with multiple templates.